# question about triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

suppose we have some triangle ABC  with AC as base.there is BE bisector and AD median ,they intersect each other  at right angle or are perpendicular,we   should find lengths of triangle.we know that bisector and median are equal  BE=AD=4. from my point of view at suppose level we can conclude that this triangle is equilateral ,because bisector and median are equal,they intersect at right angle or it seems they are perpendicular bisector or altitude?am i correct?also i think that key to solve such problem when there is not given additional information it to suppose such kind of possibilities,please help me to  solve this problem

Comment: Can you include a figure? I do not see how you conclude that "because bisector and median are equal,they intersect at right angle". Does $E$ lie on $AC$ and $D$ on $BC$?

Comment: yes   E lie on AC and D on BC unfortunately i can't include figure because from original figure is also not included

Comment: I understood your question in such a way, that both facts about bisector and median in this triangle, i.e. they are perpendicular and they have equal length, are given in the original problem.

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: I have not understood that the bisector and median are perpendicular.

Comment: here is  link for problem   http://www.naec.ge/images/doc/EXAMS/2011exam-matematika-13-ivlisii--.pdf  see problem  34,you are right  i have done badly that AC is base because triangle is given like ABC               i thought  that AC was base everything other is written i as wrote(it is georgian test)

Comment: The triangle is not equilateral. See [this](http://calcauxprobteor.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/trianglemedianbisector.jpg?w=293&h=300) figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what was provided in the discussion under @Andre's hint leads to a solution. (Probably there is a much simpler way, but I'll post my attempt anyway.)

I will denote by $M$ the intersection of $AD$ and $BC$.

**Fact 1** |AB|=|BD|, |AM|=|MD| (and also |AE|=|ED|)

**Fact 2**  $|\triangle ABE|=|\triangle BDE|=|\triangle CDE|=\frac13|\triangle ABC|$

**Fact 3** $|AE|=\frac{|AC|}3$

**Fact 4** $|\triangle AME|=\frac{|\triangle AMC|}3=\frac{|\triangle ADC|}6=\frac{|\triangle ABC|}{12}=\frac{|\triangle ABE|}4$

**Fact 5** $|EM|=\frac{|EB|}4=1$

As now I know all the lengths of AM, BM,DM, EM, I can use right triangles to calculate:

$|AB|=\sqrt{13}$

$|AE|=\sqrt{5}$ $\Rightarrow$ $|AC|=3\sqrt{5}$

$|BD|=\sqrt{13}$ $\Rightarrow$ $|BC|=2\sqrt{13}$

---

Now I can use cosine law for triangles ABE and CBE to check, whether I get the same value in both cases. (The values of the cosine should be the same, since BE is the bisector.) I get:

$\cos\frac\beta2 = \frac{13+16-5}{2.4.\sqrt{13}} = \frac{24}{8.\sqrt{13}} = \frac 3{\sqrt{13}}$

$\cos\frac\beta2 =  \frac{4.13+16-4.5}{2.4.2\sqrt{13}} = \frac{48}{16.\sqrt{13}} = \frac 3{\sqrt{13}}$.

---

You can see why the equalities from *Fact 1* hold in Andre's answer and the comments following it.

Comment: so you said that AM=MD?

Comment: @user3196 AM=MD holds for the same reasons as AB=BD (the trianglse AMB, AMD are congruent).

Comment: i    dont understand one thing  why is equal ED to BE?

Comment: yes AM=MD  i see

Comment: ok @Martin Sleziak  thank you very much i have understood solution thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The triangle is not equilateral.

[image]

Comment: and can you give me some   starting point how to solve it?

Comment: @user3196: Strong hint given.  How did the National exam go?

Comment: in general tasks was easy  but i dont know how they wrote (i had not exam )

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that $BA=BD$, so $BC=2BA$.  What familiar type of triangle does this remind you of?

Comment: my question why is that BA=BD?

Comment: @user3196 If $M$ denotes the intersection of $BE$ and $AD$, what can you say about the triangles $BMA$ and $BMD$? \\ Maybe I am missing something, but I do not see, how to continue after Andre's hint. (At least I do not see an easy way to continue.)

Comment: @user3196: Look at the two triangles that $BAD$ is divided into. They each have a right angle, and equal angles on top, so all angles correspond, the two triangles are *similar*. But the common sides are equal, so the two triangles are *congruent*.

Comment: yes i have seen already ,just i can't see what gives me BC=2*BA because if we say BC as leg (in right triangle) it means that <A=90 <B=60)i have supposed this then ,in  ABM(m as you said is intersection point) <A=60 degree, we can find AB by the sine laws(but wait it seems that AB=BD=AD=4 but in answers no one is equal to 4 so i am confused

Comment: @user3196: You should also use the fact that $AD$ is median.

Comment: median we can use in fact when we are trying to  define connection between areas of triangles(median divides triangle's are into two equal parts)i can't see where use median else

Comment: @user3196: Since AD is median, D is the midpoint of BC, which means BC=2*BD.

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak  yes  i know  i said that because  BA=BD it means that BA=BC/2   and i want to say this task was given  to childrens in national exam(when they  were passing in university)as i see  something is missed in task i am thinking yet and can't find way of solution

Comment: also  using characteristic of bisector we can say that AE/EC=1/3

Comment: sorry  AE/EC=1/2